# ActiveRecord unexpected string error upon update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Graph object which has a number of attributes, including duration:integer and parameter which is of type hstore.
Having successfully created the graph object, when I try to update duration e.g.

```
graph.update(duration: 5)
```

I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InternalError: ERROR:  Unexpected end of string
```

What is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that when saving the object for the first time, I had accidently entered another graph object e.g

```
Graph.create(duration: 2, parameter: graph_1)
```

Strangely, this worked OK, but when I tried to update it, the error was the 'Unexpected string error` was thrown. The solution was to do the create action properly by setting the parameter attribute with a hash.

```
Graph.create(duration: 2, parameter: hash_1)
```